# varImp function, caret package R, returning errors for non-tree models: Error in y - mean(y, rm.na = TRUE) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, feature-selection, caret

I have created half a dozen models through the caret package in R. Two of these models, a SVM and a pcaNN, performed well and I would like to see how they ranked the features differently from one another. The varImp function should be able to provide me with this information however when I run this function I get the following error:
`varImp_pcaNN = varImp(svmMod) Warning in mean.default(y, rm.na = TRUE) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA Error in y - mean(y, rm.na = TRUE) :  non-numeric argument to binary operator`

With previous version of caret, currently using version 6.0-94, this error did not occur. When using tree-based models, XGB and RF, I do not recieve the same error; the function works as intended and produces a list of features with their related importance values.
I used the following code to create each model (substituting the method string when appropriate):
`set.seed(420) svmMod <- train(Class ~ .,  data = train_dataset, method = "svmRadial", tuneLength = TuneLength, importance = TRUE,  trControl = train.control)`
I have tried installing previous version of caret but alas I've had no luck in managing to install previous versions correctly.

Has anyone else experienced the same issue? How did you fix it?
I've tried solving this problem on three different versions of R:
4.2.1
4.2.2
4.3.0
All with the following version of caret:
6.0-94

Comment: I managed to fix this issue, which wasn't difficult. The response feature needed to be a factor; mine was a chr!